# How to map property in application.yml to JsonNode? (Spring)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, jackson, application.properties

In a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean, I could map the `customers` property of the `application.yml` file below to `List<Customer>`, but I would like to instead map it to a Jackson `JsonNode`. Is this possible? If so, how?

```
shop:
  name: "Sam's Bikes"
  customers:
    - name: Lucy
      age: 26
    - name: James
      age: 24
```

This is what I'd like to achieve:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("shop")
public class ShopProperties() {
    private String name;
    private JsonNode customers;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to you want to map into JsonNode ? can you tell us what is your expected output ? looks like you are looking for some requirement and answer

Comment: @Deadpool I've added what I'm trying to achieve. Just wondering if there is a neat way to do this in Spring which I don't know about.

Comment: why particulaly `JsonNode` or why on `Map<String,String>` ?

Comment: In my example, `customers` is an array. But it's also possible that it could be a map, or even just a string. So I need to bind it to an object which can accomodate all these cases, like `JsonNode`.